# Oracle : sum this and this and this in a single query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have on order table  containing orders for last week and the ID of the driver who delivered them. It looks a little like this:

```
ORDERDATE,    ORDERNO,    DRIVER
23/01/2013,    901398503,    1
23/01/2013,    901332159,    1
23/01/2013,    901334158,    2
24/01/2013,    901338455,    1
25/01/2013,    902907513,    1
25/01/2013,    902338553,    2
25/01/2013,    903936533,    2
27/01/2013,    903944523,    1
27/01/2013,    903981522,    2
27/01/2013,    911334951,    1
28/01/2013,    911338851,    1
28/01/2013,    911339259,    1
28/01/2013,    912332555,    2
28/01/2013,    912336650,    2
29/01/2013,    912337655,    1
29/01/2013,    913969582,    1
29/01/2013,    913973583,    1
29/01/2013,    913982552,    1
29/01/2013,    916379158,    1
```

I'd like to select ORDERDATE, ORDERCOUNT, DRIVER_1_COUNT, DRIVER_2_COUNT.

so, date | total orders  | total orders for driver 1 | total orders for driver 2

Also, I need zeros if ORDERDATE, ORDERCOUNT, DRIVER_1_COUNT or DRIVER_2_COUNT are 0 (or null).

(In oracle) I can select dates for each day last week, and a zero order count (placeholder) for each day like this:

```
select 
 TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(sysdate,'SUNDAY')-7 +i) ORDERDATE,
 0 as ORDERCOUNT   
from
 (select rownum i from all_objects where rownum < 8)
```

I should be able to use this output to make sure there are no days missing in the final results (no orders on 26th in this example)

```
ORDERDATE,ORDERCOUNT
23/01/2013,0
24/01/2013,0
25/01/2013,0
26/01/2013,0
27/01/2013,0
28/01/2013,0
29/01/2013,0
```

I need this output:

```
ORDERDATE,ORDERCOUNT,DRIVER_1_COUNT,DRIVER_2_COUNT
23/01/2013,3,2,1
24/01/2013,1,1,0
25/01/2013,3,1,2
26/01/2013,0,0,0
27/01/2013,3,2,1
28/01/2013,4,2,2
29/01/2013,5,5,0
```

I can get ORDERDATE & ORDERCOUNT(simple sum) and union with the other query to avoid missing days, but I can't work out how to sum for each driver too.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Ed

Comment: look into `sum(case when ...`

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 11g, you can do this:-

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
PIVOT (
  COUNT( ORDERNO )
  FOR DRIVER IN (1,2,3)
)
```

For further explanation see [pivot and unpivot queries in 11g](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=506)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to summarise and crosstab results:

```
SELECT ORDERDATE, SUM(ORDERCOUNT) ORDERCOUNT, 
SUM(DECODE(DRIVER,1,ORDERCOUNT,0)) DRIVER_1_COUNT, 
SUM(DECODE(DRIVER,2,ORDERCOUNT,0)) DRIVER_2_COUNT
FROM (
    SELECT ORDERDATE, DRIVER, COUNT(*) ORDERCOUNT
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY ORDERDATE, DRIVER
) S
GROUP BY  ORDERDATE
```

There might be smarter ways to do this in Oracle

Then you need to fill in the blanks using by outer joining this to your dates:

(note the query above is aliased as 'T' in this query:)

```
SELECT D.ORDERDATE, 
NVL(T.ORDERCOUNT,0) ORDERCOUNT, 
NVL(T.DRIVER_1_COUNT,0) DRIVER_1_COUNT, 
NVL(T.DRIVER_1_COUNT,0) DRIVER_2_COUNT
FROM 
(
SELECT ORDERDATE, SUM(ORDERCOUNT) ORDERCOUNT, 
SUM(DECODE(DRIVER,1,ORDERCOUNT,0)) DRIVER_1_COUNT, 
SUM(DECODE(DRIVER,2,ORDERCOUNT,0)) DRIVER_2_COUNT
FROM 
    (
    SELECT ORDERDATE, DRIVER, COUNT(*) ORDERCOUNT
    FROM YourTable
    GROUP BY ORDERDATE, DRIVER
    ) S
GROUP BY  ORDERDATE
) T
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT
TRUNC(NEXT_DAY(sysdate,'SUNDAY')-7 +i) ORDERDATE
FROM (select rownum i from all_objects where rownum < 8)
) D
ON D.ORDERDATE = T.ORDERDATE
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to select from a subquery.  Something like this should work.

```
select orderdate, ordercount, sum(driver1) driver1count, sum(driver2) driver2count
from (
select orderdate
, case when driver = 1 then 1 else 0 end driver1
, case when driver = 2 then 1 else 0 end driver2
, count(*) ordercount

from yourtable

where whatever

group by orderdate
, case when driver = 1 then 1 else 0 end driver1
, case when driver = 2 then 1 else 0 end driver2

) you_need_an_alias_here

group by orderdate, ordercount

order by orderdate
```